# How to toggle relative number for all opened windows?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, line-numbers

I have this in my `.vimrc`:

`nnoremap <C-a> :set relativenumber!<cr>`

This toggles the relative number feature only in the current window.

Is it possible to toggle it in all opened windows with one command?

Comment: You might want to add `<silent>` to your mapping, so that the `:set` (or `:windo`) Ex command doesn't appear in the command line when you use it. Note also that the `<C-a>` keystroke is a pretty useful command (increment number, in your buffer, if you have one under the cursor of the current line), so think twice before shadowing with a mapping of your own. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, using `:h :windo`:

```
nnoremap <C-a> :windo set relativenumber!<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks. I think `<cr>` is missing

Comment: Yes! Thank you, it's fixed.